# How do you make a multiple-level button for Android?

Tags: android

As in having a switch that has levels other than "On" and "Off." Like "Off," "Low," "Medium," and "High." Is there a native API object that does that, or do I have to do it myself?

Comment: `CompoundButton` only knows checked and unchecked states, for a two-level button. You'd probably need to fork that implementation to support N levels. I cannot think of a native widget that would visually resemble a button but intrinsically tracks N levels.

Comment: I also suggest you Custom `SeekBar` with Some labels and controlled progress change.

Answer (score 0):

You have the Android [Spinner](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html), which is the Android version of a combo box.

Comment: Um, how does this address the question, which is asking about a button?

Comment: Seeing there's no such button, I thought this was the next best thing.

Comment: @zmbq This is a link-only answer; it should be a comment.